# breaking down a string into separate variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to break down a string into separate variables based on a :

Here are two possibilities of two separate strings

```
localAction:connectPage
localAction:product:<Id>
```

I want to break this down into

first variable = name

second variable (if set) = id.

Comment: `string.split()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on `esqew`'s comment...

```
var string = "localAction:connectPage";
var pair = string.split(":"); // the magic
var name = pair[0];
var id = pair[1];

console.log(name); // "localAction"
console.log(id);   // "connectPage"
```